# How to find plane equation from 8 3D points with least square method

Tags: 3d, least-squares

I have been working on school projects to find a plane equation from 8 3D points. Normally from 3 points, we can create a plane equation but when we have a lot of points, we want to find a good fitting plane for it by using Least Square Method but I’m getting stuck with the procedure to find it.
Do we have any ways to find it?
Thank you

Comment: Take the plane through the centroid and spanned by the two eigenvectors of the covariance matrix with highest eigenvalues. (In other words: perpendicular to the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue.)

Comment: Just take any three points and write the plane equation.

Comment: Look at https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf. In particular, the section *3.2 Fitting by a Plane in 3 Dimensions* may be the most interesting for you.

Comment: Are the point fairly all well aligned on a plane ? Are there outliers (erratic points) ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the equation of the best fitting plane for $n$ points
$(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n,z_n)\in\mathbb{R}^3$
can be expressed as
$$z=\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma$$
for some coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$.

To formulate this as a least squares problem let $A\in M_{n \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be defined as:
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_n & y_n & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
b = \begin{pmatrix}
z_1 \\
z_2 \\
\vdots \\
z_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now your optimization goal is to find $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^3} \left\Vert Ax-b \right\Vert^2$.
The components of the result vector $x$ will be the coefficents of the plane equation stated above i.e. $x=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.

Comment: This method will work but is not isotropic, as the $z$ axis doesn't play a role symmetrical to the others.